# Deserialization error when deserializing a generic list

Tags: c#, serialization, windows-phone

I have a generic list of objects that I am trying to serialize/desearilize.

The objects' class itself has a property of a generic list of another class,

```
class Exercise
{
    public int Duration { get; set; };
    public string Name { get; set; };
}

class Session
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public List<Exercise> ExerciseList { get; set; }
}
```

This is how serialization looks like

```
Session session = new Session((DateTime)dpDate.Value, exercises); //exercises is a List<Exercise>
...
Sessions = new List<Session>();
Sessions.Add(session);
XmlSerializer xml = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Session>));
xml.Serialize(stream, Sessions);
...
```

This is how the resulting xml looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<ArrayOfSession xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Session>
    <Date>2012-01-17T00:00:00+03:00</Date>
    <ExerciseList>
      <Exercise>
        <Name>q</Name>
        <Duration>10</Duration>
      </Exercise>
      <Exercise>
        <Name>w</Name>
        <Duration>20</Duration>
      </Exercise>
    </ExerciseList>
  </Session>
</ArrayOfSession>
```

However, when trying to deserialize it like so

```
...
XmlSerializer xml = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Session>));
Sessions = (List<Session>)xml.Deserialize(stream);
...
```

It shows the following error on the second line :

InvalidOperationException There is an error in xml document (3,4)

So what might be the problem?

**EDIT**:

I need to clarify that it is for windows phone, so the stream is formed like this

```
IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = storage.CreateFile(fileName);
Sessions = new List<Session>();
Sessions.Add(session);
XmlSerializer xml = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Session>));
xml.Serialize(stream, Sessions);
```

However, for the purpose of showing the xml structure I used

```
StringWriter s = new StringWriter();
xml.Serialize(s, Sessions);
```

So, I do not have access to the actual xml file to remove encoding="utf-16"

---

It won't let me answer my own question due to low reputation for another 5 hours, so I'll post it here:

So, the problem turned out to be not in encoding, as has been suggested.

Apparently, all the classes that are being serialized must have a default parameter less constructor present. Now that I've added them everything works splendidly. (I still do not know if it is a thing with windows phone xml serialization or xml serialization in general)

Comment: Can you try to deserialize it by removing `encoding="utf-16"?`

Comment: Completely removing or substituting with something else?

Comment: remove it completely, also provide code how you are generating the stream.

Comment: OK, I run into problem here, since it is for windows phone, running on emulator and I do not have access to the file itself, I will edit my original post to explain

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
 //Serialize
 public static string SerializeObject<T>(object o) 
 {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        XmlTextWriter xtw = new XmlTextWriter(ms, Encoding.UTF32);
        xs.Serialize(xtw, o);
        ms = (MemoryStream)xtw.BaseStream;
        UTF32Encoding encoding = new UTF32Encoding();
        return encoding.GetString(ms.ToArray());
 }

 //Deserialize
 public static T DeserializeObject<T>(string xml) 
 {
       XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
       UTF32Encoding encoding = new UTF32Encoding();
       Byte[] byteArray = encoding.GetBytes(xml);
       MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
       XmlTextWriter xtw = new XmlTextWriter(ms, Encoding.UTF32);
       return (T)xs.Deserialize(ms);
 }
```

Hope this solves your problem.

If possible go through [this](http://www.tanguay.info/web/index.php?pg=codeExamples&id=332) post.

Comment: OK, the problem was much simpler - all the classes being serialized must have a parameterless constructor. Thanks for your help, though.

Comment: Hmmm in which class you added the default constructor, because if you don't mention any constructor, by default there is a parameterless constructor is available. Also it is required by XML serializer by default, because unless and untill run time can instantiate the object it can not populate it with other property.

Comment: Both Exercise and Session classes. I know that the default constructor is always present, but apparently in case of xml serialization for windows phone, it needs to be explicitly declared in the text of the program, even if it doesn't have anything inside of it (for example my Session constructor has no parameters and nothing inside of it). And apparently it is only needed for deserialization, because it did do the serialization correctly without them.

Comment: XMLTextWriter does not exist in Silverlight library.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a closing tag for the `<ArrayOfSession>` element.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<ArrayOfSession xmlns:xsi= ...">
    <Session>
    ...
   </Session>
</ArrayOfSession>
```

Comment: Is it so? Do you know why it was formed like this when serializing? Actually, I am pretty sure it should be > (it closes in the very end with </ArrayOfSession>

Comment: Yes, sorry I missed the last line, it is actually like that.

Comment: I've just noticed that you have an/ <ArrayOfSession> in your original document. I didn't see that before! Oh well you can forget my answer.

Comment: It could be the encoding of the document, which is currently utf-16.